# birthday remainder program in php

Tags: php

Birthday alert before 1 week.
How to check current date with birthday date?
My database is MySQL

```
<?php

$birthday_query = $link->query("SELECT u.u_username, u.u_birthday
FROM ".TBL_PREFIX."users u
WHERE u.u_banned = '0'
AND u_confirmed = '1'
AND u_birthday LIKE '" . $link->asf_escape(sprintf('%2d-%2d-', $now['mday'], $now['mon'])) . "%'
ORDER BY u_username ASC");

?>
```

Its not working.

Comment: That's wonderful. What are your errors, what have you tried?

Comment: with dates You can perform normal math and date operations like adding intervals or doing date diffs...

Comment: @premkumareverestindia: No, we will not give you a "perfect coding in php". We will not do your work for you for free. This is a supportive Q&A site. You write code, you get stuck, you ask here, we help you. It's not a "These are my requirements, write my program for me" site. Forget about it.

Comment: whats your `u_birthday` date format ??

Comment: can u tell us about field "u_birthday" what it hold and its datatype.

Comment: <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("schoolapp")or die("cannot select DB");
$a=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE student_dob =DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 7 DAY)");
while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
{
 echo $b['student_id']."<br>";
 echo $b['student_name']."<br>";
 echo $b['student_dob']."<br>";
}
?>

Answer (score 1):

use mysql `NOW` & `+ INTERVAL 7 DAY` to get the 1 weeks later date from now, use `DATE_FORMAT` to specifies your u_birthday's format

try this...

```
$birthday_query = $link->query("SELECT u.u_username, u.u_birthday
                                FROM ".TBL_PREFIX."users u
                                WHERE u.u_banned = '0'
                                        AND u_confirmed = '1'
                                        AND u_birthday = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 7 DAY
                                      ORDER BY u_username ASC");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"SELECT * 
FROM your_tbl 
WHERE (DATE_ADD(YOUR_DATE, INTERVAL -7 DAY)) = " DATE(); //Your php current date
```

Comment: @Sergiu Dumitriu: how to make it as alert...